# nginx.conf reverse stream proxy - upstream not available at start up

Tags: mongodb, nginx, reverse-proxy

I try to create a nginx that a reverse proxy for 1 to 4 mongos.
But I can't guarantee that this mongos is running at the start of the nginx.

That's why I try it like this with "set":

```
stream {
    server {
        listen 123;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
        proxy_timeout 3s;
        set $test mongo_dev:27017;
        proxy_pass $test;
    }
}
```

Now I get the following error:

```
"set" directive is not allowed here
```

So I will try to make it like that:

```
stream {

    upstream stream_mongo_backend {
      server mongo_dev:27017;
    }


    server {
        listen 123;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
        proxy_timeout 3s;
        proxy_pass stream_mongo_backend;
    }
}
```

But here is the problem that my nginx isn't starting while my "mongo_dev" isn't up.

Can u give me a hint how to solve this problem?

Comment: proxi_pass is not allowed on server context, create a location for it.